# Why is Ruby's splat slower when combining arrays than using + to combine arrays?

Tags: ruby, performance

I made a wild guess that splatting an array into another would be faster than adding the two arrays together but after a quick benchmark I found out I was wrong. I assumed the interpreter would just turn the splat into an array literal and wouldn't have to call the `+` method on it every time. So, why is `+` faster than splat?

I used this benchmark code:

```
def test(trials = 1000)
  head = [1,2,3]
  tail = 100.times.to_a

  t = Time.now.to_f
  trials.times do |i| 
    a = [head, *tail]
  end
  puts "splat done in #{Time.now.to_f - t}"

  t = Time.now.to_f
  trials.times do |i| 
    a = head + tail
  end
  puts "+ done in #{Time.now.to_f - t}"
end
```

And I got this result:

```
2.2.5 :059 > test
splat done in 0.001013040542602539
+ done in 0.0009138584136962891
```

increasing the trials:

```
2.2.5 :061 > test 1_000_000
splat done in 0.5123062133789062
+ done in 0.4400749206542969
```

It's pretty close but consistently slightly faster.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "turn the splat into an array literal and wouldn't have to call the + method on it every time".

Comment: @sawa say you have `stuff = [1,2]` I thought it might replace `[1, *stuff]` with `[1, 2, 3]` therefore saving some method calls to `+` or something, not sure though.

Comment: I think benchmark-ips would be better and more accurate than just time difference

Comment: well benchmark-ips confirmed splat is slower, I wonder why :O

Comment: looking into the source of the two operations, + just do MEMCPY which is expected, it's the splat implementation that I don't understand(it involves some while loop which I think is why splat is slower)

Comment: After looking at the disassembled code, I don't think the splat operator is to blame - The version with the splat operator *is* creating one more array than the other version, but I suspect that's due to the brackets surrounding `head, *tail`.

Comment: @Sculper by the way, benchmark-ips shows the two versions as "same-ish" with rubinius :O

Comment: It is a pity that mri does not implement array literals with splats in such a way that both are equivalent in speed.  In fact, with splats it should even be faster: it can first see how much space it needs to allocate, while `+`, by its very binary nature, cannot do that.  So `[*a, *b, *c, *d]` should be faster than `a+b+c+d`.  Yet benchmarks show that the splat-way is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Why one stdlib or core feature is slower than another one?
Because it depends on types and/or data that were given to it.

Splat isn't always about arrays. It can take a `nil` and it will process it as an empty array -- here you already have some conditional behaviour, while arrays' concatenation isn't conditional but straight-forward.